# Querying usernames through database to make sure identical one doesn't exist when user wants to change their existing username

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I am trying to do is when a user decides to edit their username I would like to run a query through the database making sure that that username which they pick hasn't been taken. For the most part, I think I have it right, I run a for loop to look through all of the usernames that have been added to the database, and if one matches it shows A `Toast` message.

The issue is it shows the `Toast` message, but still changes the username even if it's in use. I know it's simple code, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Someone mind having a look? I think the issue is the `mUsername`, because I set it in the `updateProfile();` method, but if I set the new `mUserName1`, well I can't because it's an `EditText` and not a `String`.

**EditProfileActivity**

```
public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView mClose, mCheckmark, mImageProfile;
    TextView mChangePhoto;
    MaterialEditText mName, mUsername, mBio;

    private String mUsername1;
    private String mUsername2;

    FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;

    private Uri mImageUri;
    StorageReference mStorageReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);

        mClose = findViewById(R.id.close);
        mCheckmark = findViewById(R.id.post_checkmark);
        mImageProfile = findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
        mChangePhoto = findViewById(R.id.text_view_change_profile_picture);
        mName = findViewById(R.id.fullname);
        mUsername = findViewById(R.id.username);
        mBio = findViewById(R.id.bio);

        mFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                if (user != null) {
                    mName.setText(user.getFullname());
                    mUsername.setText(user.getUsername().toLowerCase());
                    mBio.setText(user.getBio());
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(mImageProfile);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        mClose.setOnClickListener(v -> new AlertDialog.Builder(EditProfileActivity.this)
                .setMessage("Exit without saving changes?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dialog, which) -> {
                    finish();
                }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show());

        mChangePhoto.setOnClickListener(v -> CropImage.activity()
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL)
                .start(EditProfileActivity.this));

        mImageProfile.setOnClickListener(v -> CropImage.activity()
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL)
                .start(EditProfileActivity.this));

        mCheckmark.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            String str_name = mName.getText().toString();
            String str_username = mUsername.getText().toString();
            String str_bio = mBio.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str_username) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_bio) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_name)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (str_username.length() > 20) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Username cannot contain more than 20 characters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                updateProfile(mName.getText().toString(), mUsername.getText().toString().toLowerCase(), mBio.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateProfile(String fullname, String username, String bio) {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid());

        mUsername1 = username.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        mUsername1 = username.replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");

        DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        reference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    if (user != null) {
                        if (user.getUsername().equals(mUsername1)) {
                            Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "That username is already in use", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                            hashMap.put("fullname", fullname);
                            hashMap.put("username", mUsername1.toLowerCase());
                            hashMap.put("bio", bio);

                            reference.updateChildren(hashMap);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a break statement after the toast message. As you loop around a list of user objects from the data snapshot. Also, You need to search for all the user object before saving.

```
 if (user.getUsername().equals(mUsername1)) {
                        Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "That username is already in use", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
                    }
```

Updates code -

```
       DatabaseReference reference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
            reference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      boolean ifUserNameExist = false;
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        if (user != null) {
                            if (user.getUsername().equals(mUsername1)) {
                                Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "That username is already in use", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           ifUserNameExist = true;
                            } 
                        }
                    }
if(!ifUserNameExist){
   HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                                hashMap.put("fullname", fullname);
                                hashMap.put("username", mUsername1.toLowerCase());
                                hashMap.put("bio", bio);

                                reference1.updateChildren(hashMap);
}
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Haha that was easy. Can you explain why though please? That legit made it work... So easy... But why do I have to add the break?

Comment: Do loop before saving? So I have to change it more, or it's fine as is? So add the HashMap outside the for loop?

Comment: @JMB Let say you already have 4 users with  username1, username2, username3, username4. Now you're loop around these 4 objects. Now, the username1 wants an update to the username to  username2. On the second loop the if-condition is satisfied so you see the toast message. Now the third loop the condition doesn't satisfy and the user data is updated. Hope it's clear.

Comment: @JMB I would suggest to add it outside the loop - have a boolean flag. You can be not sure if the username exists unless you compare it with all the usernames or if exist a break the loop and show the toast message.

Comment: Somewhat... I just tried to put the HashMap outside of the for loop and it saved a username that already exists in my database when I changed a username to another one that already exists... Can you explain or show me what you mean by the Boolean flag?

Comment: @JMB updated the answer. That should help. If not try adding a log.d statement in the code to understand where exactly you messing up. Also updated the reference variable to reference1.

Comment: Thanks brother! Works even better now with the Boolean flag I just implemented. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey what's up buddy! I have another problem similar to the one from yesterday, and I tried to solve it like we did yesterday, but it's still not working. Maybe you can have a look later...

Comment: @JMB what is the issue?

Comment: What's up man, same problem with my RegisterActivity, but for some reason the solution which you gave me above didn't work. Not sure why not. Anyways, I am still working on it, haven't figured it out yet. I would tag you in the post, but I'm not sure how...